# Wordpress CPT URL rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I'm trying to rebuild the url of my WordPress site, but without success.

I have 3 custom post types, lines, collections and products.
The idea is that they are linked by an hierarchy (one to many): lines, collections, products

So, if i have a line named L, a collection named C and a product P, i would like to access then like this:

Line A    should looks like   site.com/l

Col A     should looks like   site.com/l/c

Product A should looks like   site.com/l/c/p

i've written this code, but doesn't work properly.

In this order of rewrite rules, all the 3 urls returns Line A.

But, if i invert the order and code the rewrite rules putting the products as first, collections as second and lines as third rule, the behaviours changes.

With the inversion, the url site.com/l returns Line A, and the urls site.com/l/c and site.com/l/c/p return Col A.

I have no idea why i can't access the product page.

By the way, i'm using Types plugin to generate the CPTs and ACF plugin to generate the meta field with the relationship between the CPTs (and that's why i have the function "get_field")

```
// BACK_END
add_filter('post_type_link', 'site_type_permalink', 10, 4);

function site_type_permalink($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {

$permalink = $post_link;

if ($post->post_type == 'lines') {
    $permalink = str_replace('lines/', '', $post_link);
}

if ($post->post_type == 'collections') {
    global $post;

    $lines = get_field('line_obj');
    $title = $lines[0]->post_name;

    $permalink = str_replace('collections/', $title . '/', $post_link);
}

if ($post->post_type == 'products') {
    global $post;

    $col = get_field('collection_obj');
    $colSlug = $col[0]->post_name;
    $lin = get_field('line_obj', $col->ID);
    $linSlug = $lin[0]->post_name;

    $permalink = str_replace('products/', $linSlug . '/' . $colSlug . '/', $post_link);
 }

 return $permalink;
}


// FRONT_END
function site_rewrite_rules() {

// lines
add_rewrite_rule(
  '((?!blog|wp-json)[^/]*)/?',
  'index.php?lines=$matches[1]',
  'top'
);


// collections
add_rewrite_rule(
  '((?!blog|wp-json)[^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
  'index.php?lines=$matches[1]&collections=$matches[2]',
  'top'
);


// products
add_rewrite_rule(
  '((?!blog|wp-json)[^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
  'index.php?lines=$matches[1]&collections=$matches[2]&products=$matches[3]',
  'top'
);

}
add_action('init', 'site_rewrite_rules', 10, 0);
```

Someone have an idea what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us what the problem is. What about it "doesn't work"? Errors? White screen? Something else?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I've edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Lines, collections, products... they're all just products. Create one post type with organized taxonomies and create pages for lines/collections that query the appropriate products.

Comment: Sure this is an option. Maybe the most logical one. But making lines and collections as taxonomies; how may I guarantee the hierarchy line->collection?

Comment: You could make one taxonomy with hierarchy - parent and child terms. Then you could have site.com/line/collection/product

http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies